# Update when value is different but do not update when value is already null SQL

Tags: sql-server

Table Name - NUMBER EMPLOYEES
Columns - COMPANY ID, DIRECT, LASTUPDATEDDATE
Trigger - updateDateDETrig

I have a trigger which store the updated date in the LASTUPDATEDDATE  column when ever DIRECT column is updated.
But i want to save the date:

1. Only when the DIRECT value is different.
2. If DIRECT value is already NULL then it should not update anything and will not save any last updated date.
3. If DIRECT’s value is not NULL other value is present then it should be able to update with NULL value, in that case it should store the date too.

Trigger query -

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[updateDateDETrig]
ON [WWWSCM].[dbo].[NumberEmployees]
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS

IF ( UPDATE ([Direct]))

BEGIN

UPDATE [WWWSCM].[dbo].[NumberEmployees] SET [UpdatedDateDirectEmployees] = GETDATE ()
FROM [WWWSCM].[dbo].[NumberEmployees] t
INNER JOIN inserted i
ON t.[CompanyID] = i.[CompanyID]
END
GO
```

Update query :

```sql
update [WWWSCM].[dbo].[NumberEmployees]
set Direct = @Direct where CompanyID = @CompanyID AND (Direct<> @Direct OR Direct is NULL)
```

For me the first point is working fine , but the last 2 points are not working. Can this be done through SQL server script?

Comment: FYI, you should really have `UPDATE t`; the engine *should* be clever enough to treat the 2 references of `[WWWSCM].[dbo].[NumberEmployees]` as the same instance, but it makes it looks like you are defining 2 separate instances due to aliasing it in one place, and then *not* using its alias elsewhere.

Comment: You'll need to involve the `deleted` table, which holds the values pre-update (and I would recommend splitting insert and update triggers, since you clearly need different logic for these cases).

Comment: `IF ( UPDATE ([Direct]))` likely doesn't do what you *think* it does. It doesn't check to see if the value has updated (read changed), it checks to see if the column `Direct` is referenced in the `SET` clause of the `UPDATE` statement; if the value changes or not due to said `UPDATE` doesn't matter. `UPDATE dbo.NumberEmployees SET Direct = Direct;` would cause `IF ( UPDATE ([Direct]))` to evaluate to `TRUE`, even though not a single value was changed.